# Assigning a RecID field to Gridview TemplateField (Checbox column)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, gridview

I want to assign a RecID to the checkbox column "cbPOID". The RecID field that is being returned in my dataset, but should not be displayed in the gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" GridLines="None" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20"     
                    onpageindexchanging="gvOrders_PageIndexChanging" ForeColor="#333333">    
                    <Columns>    
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="VerifiedComplete" >    
                            <ItemTemplate>    
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbPOID" runat="server"/>    
                            </ItemTemplate>    
                        </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Rec_ID" HeaderText="Rec_ID" HtmlEncode="False"></asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PurchaseOrderID" HeaderText="PurchaseOrderID" HtmlEncode="False" ></asp:BoundField>    
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="VENDOR_ID" HeaderText="Vendor ID"></asp:BoundField>    
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="VENDOR_NAME" HeaderText="Vendor Name"></asp:BoundField>    
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ITEM_DESC" HeaderText="Item Desc"></asp:BoundField>    
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SYS_DATE" HeaderText="System Date"></asp:BoundField>    
                    </Columns>    
                    <FooterStyle CssClass="GridFooter" BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />    
                    <PagerStyle CssClass="GridPager" ForeColor="#333333" BackColor="#FFCC66" HorizontalAlign="Center" />    
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />    
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridHeader" BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"  />    
                    <RowStyle CssClass="GridItem" BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />    
                    <AlternatingRowStyle  CssClass="GridAltItem" BackColor="White" />    
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbPOID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("RecID") %>'/>
```